What should a professor do if their student writes "8" instead of "eight" in an email?
Email etiquette requires formal writing, so all numbers below ten need to be written out.
What should a professor do if their student writes "8" instead of "eight" in an email?
For example, is it against email etiquette to write the following:

Dear Mr. [Smith],
Since I need to write 8 pages for this essay, is there a minimum word count required?
Regards,
[Jane Doe]

since it has the number "8" when it should be the word "eight" written out, which means that "8 pages" should be "eight pages"?

Numbers under 10 are ALWAYS spelled out in writing. Some styles even require numbers under 100 as well as any other numbers that take fewer than three words -- to be spelled out.

Is your question whether a typical professor would consider this a violation of email etiquette? Or is your question how a professor should react to such an email?

Why do you think email etiquette requires formal writing? Is there some style manual that says so?

If the course content includes that rule of email etiquette, then the student should be advised of the breach and his/her assessment affected appropriately. To my mind that is a very big "if", and I would expect many professors would not notice that any breach of etiquette had occurred.

Why do you think this is actually some sort of "rule" rather than mere style advice? There are many possible scenarios where you would — and should — do precisely the opposite of what that would have you do.   And why in the world is this marked [tag:grammar] when it has to do with mere writing alone?

I suggest you read the letter and respond without getting upset about trivial things. Your student is not writing for The New York Times. There is no publishing stylesheets for emails. Not yet, anyway, and we hope not ever.

Numbers under 10 aren't always spelt out in all contexts. In dates and page numbers, for instance. And in mathematics and other science subjects, you wouldn't write two x = y. But emails aren't formal, and "regards" isn't a particularly formal sign-off - I'm sure Miss Manners would want something grander.

Somewhat related: Letters vs Digits: Should you write ‘Windows Seven’ or ‘Windows 7’ in an essay?

Voted to close because the question in the title is definitely off-topic and a matter of opinion (if you assume a student has transgressed and want to know what to do about the transgression, then this is the wrong place to ask - you could try Academia SE but you're likely to get a similar reaction). We could reformulate this to be slightly more on-topic, e.g. "are numbers allowed in emails?" But even that's likely to be a matter of opinion.

I must have missed the 'Email etiquette requires formal writing' edict when Parliament / Congress passed it. Move to Elbonia; emails must be edible.

The professor should remember that edicts about how and when to write out numbers as words or numerals only apply to formal pieces of academic writing. And may not apply to all subjects. They don't apply to practical communications or semi-formal communications like emails. They should also remember that respectful, practical, everyday communication is not the same as formal writing.
Generally speaking, professors should set an example of collegiate, helpful and professional behaviour for their students. This would include not pulling correspondents up on minor slips in emails. In this case, the professor would not only be setting a bad example, but would risk showing themselves to be  fool by making a point of being an unhelpful pedant while simultaneously getting the rules wrong!
